# How to discover if a software was installed on user machine via web

Tags: asp.net, winforms, activex, user-agent, agent

Here in my company we have a lot of .NET softwares both Windows Forms and Web Forms.

Now we have some challenge, we need to auditing if the user has some pirate softwares on his machine.

For Windows Forms was easy to access the windows registry.

So, how we can do for Web Sites? Cuz the user could only work on the Web Site if the AGENT was installed.

I was thinking on the Login Page, we could somehow validate if the user has the AGENT installed, if not we redirect to the new page for installing this AGENT.

PS: AGENTE will be a Windows Server.

My question is:

How can i validate via Web Site if the user has or not the AGENT installed?

Some1 has other method?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768979/detect-if-an-application-has-installed-on-the-client-machine-from-asp-net

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You can start by clarifying what the "AGENT" is? Is it some kind of software to monitor the user?

Comment: @Icarus like a say, AGENT will be a simple windows server (some click once) that will auditing information from machine (eg.pirate softwares)

Comment: Thnks Djaved, your link clarified some doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a downloadable tool on the website that audits the user's machine and provides a key that's required to login or enable the account?

Comment: Yes, its possible... But i need to validate if this AGENT was installed daily not once, cuz the user could unistall the AGENT later. So i need to validate via Web Site if the AGENT continue installed.

Comment: How about associating each agent install with a user account and having a webservice on your website that the agent posts to? The login check can then check if the agent has posted within whatever grace period your allowing.

Comment: Perfect Dave, i was thinking some like that ! Thanks for your time.
This could be the right direction.